# Resizing Tool shelf and widgets in Blender

Tags: c++, c, blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.67

[image]

In Blender, It is possible to drag the tool shelf and widgets until they fill the screen space available. But while working in blender its not good to resize the widget or tool self till it fills the screen.

so I'm trying to restrict maximizing size of the tool self and widgets. Simply disallow the resizing of Tool self and widget. **From last morning till now I didn't get proper file that where I have to made changes.**

**Where I have to make changes in Blender's source code??**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're asking in the wrong forum. Do you expect us to go through the Blender source code for you? SO is for *specific* problems. Expect the question to be closed soon.

Comment: Helow Check this link and 'comments' http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/resizing-tool-shelf-and-widgets?noredirect=1#comment6319_3732

Comment: Sure. But they told you to ask Blender developers, not developers in general.

Comment: I didn't tell you to read the full source code of Blender for me, I did ask this to whom is familiar with that, they may answer me. And there is no criteria to post on particular topics or languages. This is my research and I'm asking thats it...

Comment: You could also try [contacting blender devs directly](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact), or #blendercoders on irc.

Comment: How do you disable changing the font size in Word?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific things on blender, which should be asked on http://blender.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out the solution for this...

In source code refer  Source -> Blender -> Editors -> Screen ->     "screen_ops.c" file

In that file refer  function  "SCREEN_OT_region_scale", and stop the invoking region of function "region_scale_invoke".

Then Blender disallow you to resize the Toggle and Widget. It remains constant.

[Vismaya](http://projectvismaya.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's that simple.

[Here's `view3d_toolbar.c`](https://github.com/WChargin/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_toolbar.c), but it's not like there's a `bool is_resizable`. That sort of functionality is built into the UI itself.

The whole point of the Blender user interface is to "allow … you to change, adapt and redistribute the layout of all UI components and tools to suit the task at hand" so I don't think this will be added any time soon [[source]](http://www.blender.org/features/).

Why don't you just not resize the panels?